# Visual Studio 2010 and arduino UNO

Tags: visual-studio-2010, arduino

[image]

I try to use Arduino Uno with visual Studio 2010. I installed visualMicro but There is no arduino card detected, Sketch Project are disabled too, what is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked from the device manger if the arduino is been installed and what port is on.

Answer (score 0):

This normally means that you have selected the wrong Arduino application in the Ide locations dialog.

You can re-open the setup dialog and change the location to the correct Ide version (1.0 or 1.5)

Please use the [Visual Micro forum](http://www.visualmicro.com/forums) for assistance

Thanks